# Firebase Database Rules Permission Denied but Simulation Working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting, firebase-security

I've been trying to create a mostly public database with a few restrictions using database rules and hosting through CLI. I can access the database if I declare it open under rules, but if I remove the read/write from the top level and try to access it just one child "rules" I encounter a permissions error:

> [2018-10-04T16:13:56.926Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: set
>   at /2019/statistics/topTens/Strider Balance Bike/1 failed: permission_denied
>   Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

My database rules are:

```
{
 "rules": {
  "participants": {
   "$pid": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
   }
  },
  "statistics": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
  },
  "users": {
   "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

When I try to write to statistics even though .read and .write are true, I get the above error. Does it have something to with the database defaulting to requiring authentication? I'm also using firebase hosting to host this. I've made sure that the database-rules.json file is configured the same way as the database rules within firebase as well. I've restarted the local server with firebase serve as well, no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the error message very closely:

> set at **/2019/statistics/topTens/Strider Balance Bike/1** failed

Your write is rooted at `/2019`, not at `/statistics`, as your rule is expecting.  Your rules don't allow any writes starting with `/2019`.

Comment: Oh geez, I completely forgot I added that there. Thank you so much!